# CSS- how to set div to appear when user scrolls

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I currently have a website at http://webdevtutorials.net and it has a full-screen carousel made in bootstrap. When the user scrolls down, I would like a semitransparent div to slide up. This is the code I currently have:

```
<style>
        html, body { height:100%; }
        .carousel, .item, .active { height:100%; position:fixed; }
        .carousel-inner { height:100%; }

        @media screen and ( max-width: 350px ) {
            .carousel-caption {
                margin-bottom: 10%;
            }
        }

        @media screen and ( min-width: 350px ) {
            .carousel-caption {
                margin-bottom: 15%;
            }
        }

        #nav {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 10;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: -90px;
        }

        #content {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 5;
            margin-top: 100%;
        }
    </style>
```

The 3 nav buttons seen on the website is this:

```
<div id="nav" class="container">
```

The carousel is this:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="9000" data-ride="carousel">
```

And the div that I would like to have slide up is this:

```
<div class="row" id="content">
```

If you look on the website, the div may appear if you resize the window (I have no idea why). I am using twitter bootstrap and would like the site to be responsive.
Does anyone understand what I mean or have a possible solution?

EDIT:
The username is guest
The password is orange
Sorry I forgot to include them...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `scrollTop` and `scroll`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/ZyKar/529/

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 300) {
        $('.bottomMenu').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('.bottomMenu').slideUp();
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not really a menu. Its a long string of text. Please see the website as an example. (guest:orange)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for that:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    $("body").addClass("scrolled");
});
```

And in your CSS:

```
body div.yourclass{
    transition:transform 0.3s ease;
    transform:translate(100%);
}
body.scrolled div.yourclass{
    transform:translate(0);
}
```

A CSS only solution will be very difficult, not to say impossible.